# Filter IF in FOR Django

Tags: django

I am developing an application in Django 2.0 of courses, each course contains modules, and obviously I have the users.

**model.py**

```
Class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    .....

Class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    containt = models.TextField()
    .....

Class UserCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flat = models.BooleanField(default=False)


Class UserModule(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When the user enters the module, the registry is created in the **UserModule** model to know that it has already entered the module.

My idea is to show in the template all modules of the courses, but if the user has already made the module disable the option, otherwise allow to enter the module.

**views.py**

```
def course(request, idCourse):
   course = Course.objects.get(pk=idCourse)
   module = UserModule.objects.filter(user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id),module__course=course.id)
return render(request, 'course.html',{'course':course,'module':module})
```

This query was sent to the course template

```
{% for x in course.module_set.all %}
    {% if x in module %}
       <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
    {% else %}
       <a href="module"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But unfortunately I do not get what I need to show the link if the module has not been done

Answer (score 0):

In the template change

```
{% if x in y module %}
```

to

```
{% if x in module %}
```

Comment: I was wrong and it was over the 'and', and edit the question